# Unable to delete directories copied from elsewhere centos 6

Tags: files, permissions, cp

One of our users mistakenly copied some system directories (e.g., /lib) to her home directory, using command `cp -r /lib .`, and then she cannot delete these directories. Command `rm -rf ./lib` returns a list of errors saying "Permission denied" (one for each file, I think). I am sure both the copy and delete commands use same username, and no permission changes of any kind happened in between.

I can probably delete these directories using root privilege, but I would like to know why is this happening. Is this a bug of the Centos 6.8 we use? Or why a user cannot delete the directories she created in her home directory?

Comment: You should add some details to your question, such as: There is at least one file or directory that triggers the error message. What are ownership and permissions of this file/directory and the upper level directories? The question as stated is too unspecific to give an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cp -r` copies permission modes by default. So if `/lib` was not owner-writable, `./lib` will not be writable, either. Trying to remove the contents of a non-writable directory gets permission denied, even if you're the owner of it. You can fix the permissions with `chmod -R u+w ./lib`.

Here's a demo:

```
barmar@dev:~/test.dir$ mkdir subdir
barmar@dev:~/test.dir$ touch subdir/foo
barmar@dev:~/test.dir$ chmod a-w subdir
barmar@dev:~/test.dir$ cp -r subdir newsubdir
barmar@dev:~/test.dir$ rm -rf newsubdir
rm: cannot remove `newsubdir/foo': Permission denied
barmar@dev:~/test.dir$ chmod a+w newsubdir
barmar@dev:~/test.dir$ rm -rf newsubdir
barmar@dev:~/test.dir$
```